# A problem with propositions

Tags: propositional-calculus

**I have a trouble on this. If someone helps, it would  be great.**

$p\wedge q = 1$ and $q^ı\vee r^ı = 0$

**What is the truth value of this respectively?**

My answer:

$1,0,1$

Comment: Dear Fiv:  Even though you think you may be able to "delete" questions you ask so they go away (or else others delete them), they count with respect to the downvotes they acquire, for closure prior to deleting, and all those things are attached to you.  I am telling this to you because all closed (put on hold) questions you ask count , all questions you ask that you delete or are deleted for you count, and all downvotes the deleted posts/closed posts "earned" count in the SE's algorithm(s) for determining when a user loses the privilege to ask questions.

Comment: I'm just trying to give you "heads up".  I don't know how many questions you've asked, but deleted.  I only know of two questions you've asked, one of which you deleted.  If that's all there's been, then relax, but please know that if the pattern you've shown with these two questions continue, you may run into a wall rather quickly.  Please use the help menu, and in particular, read through the entries given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/asking) which deal with "asking" and includes "How to ask a good question."

Comment: Rule reminder: Don't create another account to get around a system placed limitation such as a question ban. The remedy is to improve your own questions. Now it seems that you managed to climb out of QB. Good job! Please pay attention to the quality of your questions in the future. I deleted the other account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition

$$ p \wedge q = 1 $$

implies that $p = 1$ and $q = 1$. This means that

$$ q^\prime \vee r^\prime =  0 \vee r^\prime = r^\prime = 0$$

From the above we conclude $r = 1$. Thus $\{p,q,r\} = \{1,1,1\}$

Comment: You can also use the rule of de Morgan : $q'\ or\ r'=(q\ and\ r)'$. This gives $q\ and\ r=1$ and therefore $q=1$ and $r=1$

Comment: Yes, as @Peter points out, de Morgan's rule will also work. If you will be studying logic then de Morgan's rules are very helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great answer! If you show the rule of de Morgan (or someone) i'd be happy.

Comment: Can someone solve this question with de Morgan's rule?